# Native Memory Spike during JIT Compilation due to a Lambda Function

Tags: java, performance, lambda, jvm, jit

Summary of the issue:

There was a common java method(say methodCausingProblem() whose compiled size is around 4KB) used for all requests in which we faced some native memory spike(around 2GB) during C2 compilation. The strange thing in that method was a lambda function. After removing that suspicious code, the issue seemed to be resolved. **But we are still unable to find the actual reason for memory spikes**

Debugging path:

With the help of Native memory tracking, profilers(perf and jem), core dump analyzers(gdb and hsdb), we were able to identify the problematic method.

```java
public static void methodCausingProblem() {

    // some content
    DefaultValue obj=() -> mymethod("Dummy");
    String data=obj.func(); 
    // some content

}


public static String mymethod(String rel) throws Exception{
    return rel;
}

public static interface DefaultValue {
        String func() throws Exception;
}
```

More details of the issue:

When analyzed using profilers, the memory growth was during PhaseChaitin Register_Allocation and we couldn't find anything suspicious from the respective Machine Code. As per our knowledge this is some optimization based on the spill check and decision is made for the register allocation.

Native Stack trace which took more memory:

```
_ZNK4Node13rematerializeEv + 0x20
    _ZN12PhaseChaitin5SplitEjP12ResourceArea + 0x9a0
    _ZN12PhaseChaitin17Register_AllocateEv + 0x9fd
    _ZN7Compile8Code_GenEv + 0x2bb
    _ZN7CompileC1EP5ciEnvP10C2CompilerP8ciMethodibbb + 0x1260
    _ZN10C2Compiler14compile_methodEP5ciEnvP8ciMethodi + 0x20c
    _ZN13CompileBroker25invoke_compiler_on_methodEP11CompileTask + 0xd46
    _ZN13CompileBroker20compiler_thread_loopEv + 0x657
    _ZN10JavaThread17thread_main_innerEv + 0xf1
    _ZL10java_startP6Thread + 0x132
```

[Perf snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdMph.png)

Compilation event:

```
<nmethod compile_id='32976' compiler='C2' level='4' entry='<hex>' size='444608' address='<hex>' relocation_offset='296' insts_offset='23920' stub_offset='251280' scopes_data_offset='266328' scopes_pcs_offset='341304' dependencies_offset='418600' handler_table_offset='418832' nul_chk_table_offset='443168' oops_offset='265072' method='<problematicMethod(arg1..argn)>' bytes='4191' count='1295' backedge_count='17962' iicount='1295' stamp='1042.504'/>
```

--Edited--

We have many lambda functions in our application, but only at this place issue occurred. We want to dig deeper in this method to identify the actual issue to arrest such issues in future.

Any ideas for debugging it deeper?

--Updated--

Native Memory growth occurs only when the lambda method is called in a specific point in the affected method.

Comment: I didn't notice a question mark here. This looks more like a bug report, but Stack Overflow is not an OpenJDK bugtracker.

Comment: Sorry. Have edited my question, kindly check now. @apangin

Comment: A method with 4K bytecodes is pretty huge - have you tried splitting it into multiple methods? What is VM version? Does the footprint still increase much when running JVM with jemalloc? Try decreasing `-XX:MaxNodeLimit` and `-XX:LiveNodeCountInliningCutoff`.

Comment: Thanks @apangin, issue doesn't occur when splitting the affected method into two and also issue doesn't occur(without method splitting) when the MaxNodeLimit is decreased(Compilation is skipped during live-range split). But I want to know whether the lambda function created more nodes? Any possibility to print node size of methods during compilation?

Comment: Yes: `-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+LogCompilation`. Then look for `<phase ... nodes='xxx' live='yyy' >` in the compilation log.

Comment: @apangin Already checked that, <phase..> is not printing in my compilation logs?

Comment: What is printed in your compilation logs?

Comment: @apangin <task_queued...>, <method...> and <made_not_entrant...> details are only available in my compilation logs

Comment: This is VM log, not the compilation log. Do not specify `-XX:+LogVMOutput`. Just these two options: `-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+LogCompilation`.